# How to set timer for random colour in swift 2?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

i want to set timer and change the background color every 5 seconds.

I wrote code of random color and its work perfect , but i tried to put the function in NSTimer and i getting crush.

> 2016-03-05 14:46:48.774 Boo Adventure[6782:365555] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Boo_Adventure.GameScene update]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fe2cb741ac0'

**Game Scene :**

```
extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}


extension UIColor {
    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let r = CGFloat.random()
        let g = CGFloat.random()
        let b = CGFloat.random()

        // If you wanted a random alpha, just create another
        // random number for that too.
        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 2.5)
    }
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        func update() {

            self.view!.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()

        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues here:

1) You want to change color every 5 seconds, but you set `repeats` parameter to `false`, so your custom update() method will be executed only once. Change `repeats` to `true`.

2) You are trying to change the background color of a view (SKView) instead of a background color of the scene.

Here is how you can do it with `NSTimer`:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update(){
      backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
}
```

But `NSTimer` is not affected by the scene's or view's paused state, so it can take you into troubles in certain situations. To avoid this, you can use `SKAction`. The same thing done with SKAction looks like this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(5)

        let block = SKAction.runBlock({
            [unowned self] in
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
        })

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait,block])

        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence), withKey: "colorizing")

    }
```

This way, if you pause your scene or a view, colorizing action will be paused automatically (and unpaused when scene/view are unpaused).

Comment: How i can add it transition?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use [colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration:) But that is another topic and  you should ask a new question  ...

Answer (score 0):

your function `update` looks like it's in a closure for the timer - but it's not.  take the function out so that it looks like this

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
   Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func update() {
    self.view!.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this fixes the problem but according to the [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) the selector should have the signature:

```
timerFireMethod:
```

Try updating your `update` function signature to

```
func update(timer: NSTimer)
```

And update this line:

```
Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

to:

```
Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: what i need to put in timerFireMethod ?